# Add root with static values to xml file create by SQL query

Tags: sql, xml

The following creates an xml file in the format shown at the bottom. I got a requirement from our 3rd application developer that there needs to be an upper root (? or namespace ?) above the current root. I have zero idea on how to accomplish this.

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
        ProductID nvarchar(25) NULL,
        [Name] nvarchar(25) NULL,
        ParentID nvarchar(51) NULL,
        AttributeType nvarchar(10) NULL,
        AttributeID nvarchar(255) NULL,
        AttributeValue nvarchar(4000) NULL
);

INSERT INTO @tbl (ProductID, [Name], ParentID, AttributeType, AttributeID, AttributeValue)
VALUES 
('1557505','DVSCTV-HT','39122206_5183','Value','IDW_EnvironmentalConditions','Indoor use only'),
('1557505','DVSCTV-HT','39122206_5183','Value','IDW_Enclosure','Plastic'),
('1557505','DVSCTV-HT','39122206_5183','MultiValue','IDW_Color','Hot'),
('1557505','DVSCTV-HT','39122206_5183','MultiValue','IDW_Color','Purple'), 
('1557505','DVSCTV-HT','39122206_5183','MultiValue','IDW_Color','Yellow');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ProductID AS [@ID]
    , 'CatalogNumber' AS [@UserTypeID]
    , ParentID AS [@ParentID]
    , Name AS [Name]
    , (SELECT AttributeType, AttributeID, AttributeValue
        FROM @tbl AS c
        WHERE p.ProductID = c.ProductID
            AND p.ParentID = c.ParentID
            AND p.[Name] = c.[Name]
        FOR XML PATH('r'), TYPE, ROOT('root')
).query('<Values>
{
    for $x in /root/r[AttributeType="Value"]
    return <Value AttributeID="{data($x/AttributeID)}">{data($x/AttributeValue)}</Value>,
    <MultiValue AttributeID="{(/root/r[AttributeType="MultiValue"]/AttributeID/text())[1]}">
    {
        for $x in /root/r[AttributeType="MultiValue"]/AttributeValue/text()
        return <Value>{$x}</Value>
    }
    </MultiValue>
}
</Values>')
FROM @tbl AS p
GROUP BY ProductID, ParentID, [Name]
FOR XML PATH('Product'), TYPE, ROOT('Products');
```

Here is the formatted output:

```
<Products>
  <Product ID="1557505" UserTypeID="CatalogNumber" ParentID="39122206_5183">
    <Name>DVSCTV-HT</Name>
    <Values>
      <Value AttributeID="IDWIndexID">10706063</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="IDW_ChangeFlag">A</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="IDW_StockIndicatorLOV">S</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="IDW_GTIN">00027557663526</Value>
      <MultiValue AttributeID="IDW_Color">
        <Value>Hot</Value>
        <Value>Plastic</Value>
      </MultiValue>
    </Values>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

But i need a root above this with static values so the output should look like this:

```
<STEP-ProductInformation ImportContext="Context1" ContextID="Context1" WorkspaceID="Main" UseContextLocale="false"> 
    <Products>
        <Product ID="1557505" UserTypeID="CatalogNumber" ParentID="39122206_5183">
            <Name>DVSCTV-HT</Name>
            <Values>
                <Value AttributeID="IDWIndexID">10706063</Value>
                <Value AttributeID="IDW_ChangeFlag">A</Value>
                <Value AttributeID="IDW_StockIndicatorLOV">S</Value>
                <Value AttributeID="IDW_GTIN">00027557663526</Value>
                <MultiValue AttributeID="IDW_Color">
                    <Value>Hot</Value>
                    <Value>Plastic</Value>
                </MultiValue>
            </Values>
        </Product>
    </Products>
</STEP-ProductInformation>
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I already answered your question here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1206730/need-to-create-a-formatted-xml-file-using-sql-quer

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above SQL is product specific.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
        ProductID nvarchar(25) NULL,
        [Name] nvarchar(25) NULL,
        ParentID nvarchar(51) NULL,
        AttributeType nvarchar(10) NULL,
        AttributeID nvarchar(255) NULL,
        AttributeValue nvarchar(4000) NULL
);

INSERT INTO @tbl (ProductID, [Name], ParentID, AttributeType, AttributeID, AttributeValue)
VALUES 
('1557505','DVSCTV-HT','39122206_5183','Value','IDW_EnvironmentalConditions','Indoor use only'),
('1557505','DVSCTV-HT','39122206_5183','Value','IDW_Enclosure','Plastic'),
('1557505','DVSCTV-HT','39122206_5183','MultiValue','IDW_Color','Hot'),
('1557505','DVSCTV-HT','39122206_5183','MultiValue','IDW_Color','Purple'), 
('1557505','DVSCTV-HT','39122206_5183','MultiValue','IDW_Color','Yellow');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT 'Context1' AS [@ImportContext]
    , 'Context1' AS [@ContextID]
    , 'Main' AS [@WorkspaceID]
    , 'false' AS [@UseContextLocale]
, (
SELECT ProductID AS [@ID]
    , 'CatalogNumber' AS [@UserTypeID]
    , ParentID AS [@ParentID]
    , Name AS [Name]
    , (SELECT AttributeType, AttributeID, AttributeValue
        FROM @tbl AS c
        WHERE p.ProductID = c.ProductID
            AND p.ParentID = c.ParentID
            AND p.[Name] = c.[Name]
        FOR XML PATH('r'), TYPE, ROOT('root')
).query('<Values>
{
    for $x in /root/r[AttributeType="Value"]
    return <Value AttributeID="{data($x/AttributeID)}">{data($x/AttributeValue)}</Value>,
    <MultiValue AttributeID="{(/root/r[AttributeType="MultiValue"]/AttributeID/text())[1]}">
    {
        for $x in /root/r[AttributeType="MultiValue"]/AttributeValue/text()
        return <Value>{$x}</Value>
    }
    </MultiValue>
}
</Values>')
FROM @tbl AS p
GROUP BY ProductID, ParentID, [Name]
FOR XML PATH('Product'), TYPE, ROOT('Products')
)
FOR XML PATH('STEP-ProductInformation'), TYPE;
```

**Output**

```
<STEP-ProductInformation ImportContext="Context1" ContextID="Context1" WorkspaceID="Main" UseContextLocale="false">
  <Products>
    <Product ID="1557505" UserTypeID="CatalogNumber" ParentID="39122206_5183">
      <Name>DVSCTV-HT</Name>
      <Values>
        <Value AttributeID="IDW_EnvironmentalConditions">Indoor use only</Value>
        <Value AttributeID="IDW_Enclosure">Plastic</Value>
        <MultiValue AttributeID="IDW_Color">
          <Value>Hot</Value>
          <Value>Purple</Value>
          <Value>Yellow</Value>
        </MultiValue>
      </Values>
    </Product>
  </Products>
</STEP-ProductInformation>
```

Comment: Runs perfectly. The only question that remains is that when I run this to create a file through SSIS (C# script task) it will create a blank file if there are no results. When I say blank file it has these two lines and that's it...<?xml version="1.0"?>
<STEP-ProductInformation UseContextLocale="false" WorkspaceID="Main" ContextID="Context1" ImportContext="Context1"/>...... so I was curious to find out how to prevent an empty file from being created if there are no results.

Comment: I guess I can just add a row count or something to look at the table the file is being created from and if nothing then do this if some data then create file. Good enough. Unless there is some better stock option out there that I'm unaware of.

Comment: It is better to package XML generating T-SQL code as a stored procedure (SP). And call that SP via bcp.exe. Please ask a new question, and I will show how to do that.